# Memory handling of large python recarray for quick read and write on GridEngine

Tags: python, memory-management, sungridengine, large-data

Is there any way to force a python2.7 object to be held in RAM for quick read and write accessing? Or if this is an OS dependent matter is there anyway to get Grid Engine to do the same?

I have a large Global recarray (myrecarray) consisting of 19 fields and 50 million of rows. I am using a definition (myloop) to loop over myrecarray visiting each row once to update the value of 2 fields and to copy some data to other objects. This is being run via qsub on a cluster with 256GB RAM (~10x the size of myrecarray so it can cope with the size of myrecarray). The issue here is the loop is a huge bottleneck when run on the cluster. When testing the loop with the same 500,000 row recarray using timeit on a macbook pro (4GB RAM, 2.53 GHz processor) the loop takes 250^-6 seconds and is 5x faster than on the cluster.

It seems most likely that the cluster is not holding myrecarray in the RAM but is forcing the loop to read it from the disc each time, thus causing the slowdown.

I have looked into memory sharing on the grid engine, multiprocessing in python and Heap allocation and have got a little lost, especially as I am not sure what is exactly going on. Any suggestions will be warmly welcomed

An example row of the recarray is...

```
(49817038, 'C', 'R', 'O', 'U', 'E', 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 2, 0, 'Tup', 'Hit')
```

N.B. I am the only person using this cluster so there are no conflicts with other jobs, this is a single threaded process and there are no limits set on RAM usage by the administrator.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an OS setting. Look at how to configure your swappiness factor. If you want to keep everything in RAM unless it's full, set it to 0.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer @Finch_Powers, I am just checking this with the administrator of the cluster. I hope you are right, This solve a huge issue if it is correct.

Comment: The swappiness is set at the default of 60, which suggests that it should only stat swapping out when ~150GB of RAM is occupied on this system, The RAM as checked by viewing "top" during the run or via qacct after the job has finished get nowhere near this figure. do you still think this could be the problem? cheers

Comment: I do not know. Did you try setting it to zero to compare how it behaves?

Comment: Not yet, I am waiting on the admin to do it, I am not a priviliged user on the cluster; it won't let me do a non-root user change to 0. just thought I'd ask the logical question. Cheers